# Using crontab in general but in Jenkins specifically

Tags: jenkins, cron

I have a jenkins project currently scheduled thusly

```
30 4 * * 1-5
```

Just this weekend they want us to run it also in the weekend, so I was curious as to whether I could have two lines.  Something like

```
30 4 * * 1-5
00 16 6,7 8 0,6
```

which I believe, if it works, should schedule for August 6th when it falls on a Saturday or Sunday, and August 7th when it falls on a Saturday or Sunday, and will still run at 4:30 am M-F.  Is that correct?  Will two lines work?  More than two (i.e., unlimited number of lines)?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple entries in jenkins crontab form will work.

Answer (score 0):

The first line will run just as you said M-F @ 4:30am.

The second will run at 4pm on August 6th and 7th if they fall on a Saturday or Sunday. It will run every year.

Reference: http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference

Comment: Only years where 8/6 or 8/7 (Europe 6/8 and 7/8), either one, is on a sat or sun.  I figured I would remember by then to remove the second line.  If I made them run more often I might forget before it want the next weekend ;-)